# Digitization scale

Tags: scale

What is the relationship between the map scale and the digitization scale? Is there any rule?

In my case, I'm making a map at 1:35'000. At what scale would you digitize the roads from satelite image?

Answer (score 2):

If you can make shure, that your map scale will not change to a larger scale then it would be sufficient if you digitize your roads in 1:35000. Be aware that this can be a generalization in some situations (very curved road network). If in the future your road data will be needed for larger scaled maps, consider digitizing at at larger scale. Consider the more work as a good future investment for any secondary use of your data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to digitize at that Map scale at 35,000, just remember that when someone zooms it in further , the line will be a bit shift, so I would recommend to zoom around 12,000 or lower then this way your digitize will be more precise than at the 35,000.

So will your project be just a small local area or whole wide area ?

Comment: thank you for your recommendation . It's a huge Area. 1:12'000 is fine.